# do i really need 4 lines of code to get a value from the middle of a string?

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to get a value from a file path.
assume my path looks like any other path:

```
c:\SomeFolder\SomeOtherfolder\A_Specific_Folder\what_i_want\another_folder\bla.txt
```

I can infer the name of 'A_Specific_Folder' at runtime, and i need to get 'what_i_want'.
I know that 'what_i_want' is a number

I currenly use a regex like this:

```
public String getValueThatIneed(String path) {
    String regex = String.format("%s\\\\([0-9]+)\\\\", varContainingNameOfSpecificFolder); 
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = compile.matcher(path);
    matcher.find(); \\because otherwise i can't use matcher.start()
    String myValue = path.substring(matcher.start(1), matcher.end(1));
    return myValue;
}
```

All this just to get this tinyValue from one String.
Now assume that i must have this in a method because I use it in 10 places.
But in one of the places I suddenly need to do some other operation on the stirng that would again require me to do all the patter, matcher stuff, with the same regex, just to get matcher.end(1), because maybe thats all i need over there.

Is there shorter way to do this?

thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with accepting a second parameter with the match number?

Comment: The reason to use `find()` is to apply the regex and find out whether it matched.  If you don't call `find()` (or `matches()` or `lookingAt()`) **and check the return value**, you don't know that it's safe to call `start()`, `end()`, `group()`, or other methods that depend on the Matcher's state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several minor problems in your code:

- If `varContainingNameOfSpecificFolder` contains characters that have a meaning in regular expressions (`.` being the most likely candidate), then you **must** use `Pattern.quote()` to quote that part.
- your use of `String.format()` is unnecessary, you can use simply `String` concatenation using `+` here, which is easier to read.
- you don't need the assignment to `myValue`, simply `return` the result of `substring`
- the `substring` call is *unnecessary* here! Simply replacing that expression with [`matcher.group(1)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) has the same effect!
- using [`String.replaceAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) might be a valid shortcut, but you'd have to modify your regex slightly.

So my version would be:

```
public static String getValueThatIneed(String path) {
    String regex = ".*\\\\" + Pattern.quote(varContainingNameOfSpecificFolder) + "\\\\([0-9]+)\\\\.*";
    String result = path.replaceAll(regex, "$1");
    if (result.equals(path)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("<" + path + "> does not contain the thin i need!");
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you don't care about error checking (as your code doesn't do it either) you can simply *return* the result of the `replaceAll()` method and have a two-line method:

```
public static String getValueThatIneed(String path) {
    String regex = ".*\\\\" + Pattern.quote(varContainingNameOfSpecificFolder) + "\\\\([0-9]+)\\\\.*";
    return path.replaceAll(regex, "$1");
}
```

However, I **strongly** encourage you to keep it, as otherwise you can easily miss nasty bugs in your code.

Comment: can you show an example of how to use String.replaceAll() for this task? thanks

Comment: @dan: i demonstrated it on my version, see the second code block.

Comment: Thanks. great answer. can you explain why in my version i don't need ".*" at the beginning and the end of the regex and it works with group(1), and in your version you added ".*" and witout it, it doesnt work with $1?

Comment: @dan: the difference is how you use the regex: you simply search for the regex, i.e. you don't care *what exactly* it matches, but just that it matches the thing you want as its first group. I *replace* everything the regex matches with the first group. Since I want *only* the first group to remain, I need the regex to match the *whole string*.

Comment: Thanks. I like this answer. It may seem odd that I need folderName and i prefer using string manipulation instead of File API, but in this case it gives me more flexibilty. I didnt right it in the original question, but I also need, in one of the use cases, to take the remaining path after the "what_i_want". in this case i just use adjust the regex to contain 2 groups.

Comment: If you need more than one part of the path, then using `replaceAll` will no longer work, and you should use the `Matcher`/`find` approach. Also note that if `A_Specific_Folder` is always the same, then you can prepare the `Pattern` in a `static` variable and re-use it (instead of recreating it each time).

Comment: why won't it work? In my case i need my original value and the rest of the path, so i changed the regex to String regex = ".*\\\\" + Pattern.quote(varContainingNameOfSpecificFolder) + "\\\\([0-9]+)\\\\(.*)" - meaning, i added another group, and then i use path.replaceAll(regex, "$2"). it works when i run it. Any problem with it?

Comment: @dan: yes, that would work, but you'd need to call `replaceAll()` twice. And I'd consider that a pretty ugly approach (since using `replaceAll()` instead of `find()` is already *slightly* hacky). Using find in this case is much more readable and understandable. Also note the change I added to my answer (`substring` is not necessary here!)

Answer (score 5):

I'd use the File API and check the parent name:

```
public String find(File file, String folder) {
    while (file.getParentFile() != null) {
        if(file.getParentFile().getName().equals(folder)) return file.getName();
        file = file.getParentFile();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Or the recursive equivalent:

```
public static String find(File file, String folder) {
    if(file.getParentFile() == null) return null;
    if(file.getParentFile().getName().equals(folder)) return file.getName();
    return find(file.getParentFile(), folder);
}
```

Comment: well it can do the job, but i started my question with wondering why i need so many code lines just to get that middle folder in the path. So  a loop doesnt feel right for this task.

Comment: That's probably the best way! Added bonus points for being cross-platform compatible!

Comment: What is it with people not liking loops? **Everything** uses loops. Using regular expressions and `indexOf` and `split` simply *hides* those loops from your view, it doesn't make them go away!

Comment: Yep, 'File' offers you a language API method of solving your problem, in less code and without any messy regex. This code obviously says - "I want the name of the folder under A_Specific_Folder in the file path". None of the other solutions express the implementation in the domain language of files and folders.

Comment: Want to do it in one line of code, without a loop? Use recursion:
`public String find(File file, String folder) {
return file.getParentFile() == null ? null : (file.getParentFile().getName().equals(folder) ? file.getName() : find(file.getParentFile(), folder));
}`
But the while loop is easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

With [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) you can go with this:

```
String whatIWant = StringUtils.substringBetween(FilenameUtils.separatorsToUnix(path), specificFolder + "/", "/");
```

A readable One-Liner being cross-platform compatible.

You may want to consider using `FilenameUtils.normalize(path, true)` instead of `FilenameUtils.separatorsToUnix(path)` when you want to get rid of double and single dot path steps.

Comment: With `FilenameUtils`, you get `normalize()` which gives you a path that always uses `/` as separator, so it's even possible to write this code in a portable way (normalize and then use `specificFolder + '/'`).

Comment: @Aaron Done. Had to use `normalize(String, boolean)` since `normalize(String)` does not touch the file separator.

Comment: Finally used `FilenameUtils.separatorsToUnix(String)`. Uff :)

Answer (score 1):

A two-liner (just to prove that it can be done):

```
private static String getNumber(String path, String folder) {
  String[] splits = path.split(String.format("\\\\folder\\\\", folder);
  return splits[1].substring(0,splits[1].indexOf('\\')));
}
```

Note that this *only* works with *correct* input. paths that don't contain the folder name or don't have a number at the right place will cause various runtime exceptions. Robust code needs a lot more lines of code...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the substring is always the 4th, this may fit your needs:

```
    public String getValueThatIneed(String path) {
        return (path.split("\\\\"))[3];
    }
```

EDITED to show it is possible in just a single line.

Comment: Note that you need to split for `"\\\\"` since `split` expects a regex. Also, assuming it is always the 4th position is a great way to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @Simon stelling: You are right. Corrected the regex. Yes, the direct access to the array is risky. A safe code would chech for the method argument nullity, the returned array nullity and length, and maybe also catch PatternSyntaxException if the regex could vary in the future.

Comment: @MisterSmith: actually `split()` can't ever return `null`. It *either* returns an array *or* throws an exception.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there shorter way to do this?

Of course; it's trivial to just elide the temporaries. Also, don't hide your dependencies. Oh, and `Matcher` already provides an interface for "give me the part that was matched by the entire pattern", so we don't need to look it up in the original string.

```
public String getValueThatIneed(String path, String toFind) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(String.format("%s\\\\([0-9]+)\\\\", toFind)).matcher(path);
    matcher.find();
    return matcher.group(1);
}
```

Comment: Just a bit fussy: He wants capturing group 1 and not group 0.

Comment: I hadn't noticed there were capturing parentheses at all, somehow. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid costly regular expressions:

```
public String getValueThatIneed(String path) {
   int startIndex = path.indexOf( File.separator + varContainingNameOfSpecificFolder + File.separator ) + varContainingNameOfSpecificFolder.length() + 2;
   return ( startIndex < varContainingNameOfSpecificFolder.length() + 2 ) ? "" : path.substring( startIndex, path.indexOf( File.separator, startIndex ) ); 
}
```